# Error Jquery no escucha click php

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

Poseo una función que muestra un listado y lo coloca en el div `ZonaListados`, lo hace perfecto.  En el listado hay un link que posee una clase llamada `VerPubli`. Al hace click se abre un modal llamado `MyModalFormUso` que es llamado en distintas oportunidades.
En este caso en un div del modal que posee una clase llamada `BotonFormCargaUso`, se carga un boton con sus clase respectivas. Hasta aquí lo hace perfectamente.

```
$('.BotonFormCargaUso').html("<a href='#' class='btn AplicarCandidatos' type='btn'  name='Aplicador' class='btn fancy-btn fancy-dark bg-transparent ' id='Aplicador' ><i class = 'ti-user '></i>&nbsp; Aplicar Uso</a>");

        $('#myModalFormUso').modal({show:true});
```

El problema es que ese botón tiene que ser detectado por Jquery en

```
 $('.AplicarCandidatos').on('click', function(e) {
```

y no lo hace, no se que sucede...

va código completo:

```
 function listarS(aTipo){
    $.ajax({
        url:'../phpAux/ListadoBusquedas21.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'Tipo=' +aTipo,
        beforeSend: function () {
        $('.ZonaListados').html('<h5><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>Buscando Publicaiones...</h5>"');
        },            
        success: function (data) {    
            $('.ContieneBusquedas').show(50);               
            $(".ZonaListados").html(data); 
           $(document).ready(function(){     
                 $('.VerPubli').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();        
                //var eNombrePuesto = $(this).data('nombrepuesto');
                $('.NuevaEdit').html("Publicacion");

                $('#NombrePuesto').val($(this).data('nombrepuesto')).prop('readonly', true); 
                $('#UbicacionPuesto').val($(this).data('ubicacionpuesto')).prop('readonly', true);

                $('.BotonFormCargaUso').html("<a href='#' class='btn AplicarCandidatos' type='btn'  name='Aplicador' class='btn fancy-btn fancy-dark bg-transparent ' id='Aplicador' ><i class = 'ti-user '></i>&nbsp; Aplicar Uso</a>");

                $('#myModalFormUso').modal({show:true});
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    /*     script ENVIO DE FOPRMULARIO Publicacion Uso-->   */    
                    $('.AplicarCandidato').on('click', function(e) { 
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#myModalFormUso').hide();                        
                        $('#myModalAplicaCandidato').modal({show:true});                      

                    })                

                });

            })
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                /*     script ENVIO DE FOPRMULARIO AplicacioCandidato PUESTO-->   */    
                $('.AplicarCandidatos').on('click', function(e) { 
                    e.preventDefault();        
                    $('#myModalAplicaCandidato').modal({show:true});
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'../phpAux/SelectCandidatos.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data:'Tipo=1',
                        beforeSend: function () {
                        //nada
                        },                        
                        success: function (data) {   
                            $('.SelectCandidatos').html(data);
                        }
                    })

                })


            });



        },       


    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, tu botón se crea de forma dinámica y esta dentro del modal, puedes añadir un evento al modal para que te lo reconozca, aunque fuera creado después de cargar la pagina, de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#myModalFormUso').on('click', '.AplicarCandidatos', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModalFormUso').hide();                        
    $('#myModalAplicaCandidato').modal({show:true});                      

})
```

Comment: Hola Dark FUNCIONO, cierra el modal, va al otro modal pero cuando este nuevo lo cierro, la pagina queda oscura, como si no se hubiera cerrado el modal. tal vez la funcion no sea
   $('#myModalFormUso').hide();    
se hace de otra forma?

Comment: Al final use: 
`$('#myModalFormUso').modal('toggle');`
Y funciona perfecto..!! Gracias